# How to get the Open Graph User Generated Images Flag working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, http-post, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to post open-graph actions with large photos as described in the OG documentation:

[Adding Photos to Stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/adding-photos-to-stories/)

My action is already approved for all optional actions including user-generated photos.

Whenever I issue this action the story still appears in ticker as if there was not a user-generated photo included in the post request.  No Album is created for my app and obviously the photo is not added to said album.

Is there some undocumented behavior that I should be following?  Should I be omitting the og:image in the headers of the Object this action is taking place on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem.

The documentation was wrong in the examples section on this topic on facebook docs.

Their example had dashes where underscores are needed: i.e.

**user-generated = user_generated**

```
POST /me/cookbook:eat?
recipe=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/&
image[0][url]=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/pizza.jpg&
image[0][user-generated]=true&
image[1][url]=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/pizza2.jpg&
image[1][user-generated]=true&
access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

should be

```
POST /me/cookbook:eat?
recipe=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/&
image[0][url]=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/pizza.jpg&
image[0][user_generated]=true&
image[1][url]=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/pizza2.jpg&
image[1][user_generated]=true&
access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

In case anyone else runs into this before they fix the documentation.  Opened a bug report: [Bug Report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/636543626362066)